# Python Scatter plot not working with "None" points

Tags: python, list, scatter-plot

Say I create three lists:

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
z=[1,None,4]
```

How can I scatter this and simply only include the points with numbers (i.e. exclude the "none" point). My code won't produce a scatter plot when I include these lists (however when I include a number instead of "None" it works):

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib notebook


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')



plt.show()
```

Comment: I suppose this depends on how you want to deal with 2D points in your 3D plot, but the simple solution to exclude the None point is to replace None values with np.nan. Alternatively, you may want to preserve all 3 points, in which case you can replace with 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
import numpy as np
```

and replace your `None` with a `np.nan`. The points containing `np.nan` will not be plotted in your scatter plot. See [this matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/masked_demo.html) for more information.

If you have long lists containing `None`, you can perform the conversion via

```
array_containing_nans = np.array(list_containing_nones, dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.nan` instead of `None`

```
import numpy as np
z=[1,None,4]
z_numpy = np.asarray(z, dtype=np.float32)

.... 

ax.scatter(x, y, z_numpy, c='r', marker='o')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NaNs` instead of `None` which is not the same thing. A `NaN` is a float.

**Minimal example**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
z=[1,np.nan,4]

plt.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```